# I'm developing a programing language extension for visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, tmlanguage

I'm developing a programing language extension for visual studio code, and I need help with highlighting code.

Comment: read the syntax of TextMate grammers. Use other language extensions as examples, https://github.com/rioj7/vscode-behave/blob/master/behave.tmGrammar.json for a simple language

Comment: Stack Overflow is neither a discussion forum nor a tutorial, code-writing, or homework service. This is a Q&A site where *specific* programming questions (usually, but not always, including some code) get *specific* answers. Please take the [tour] and carefully read through the [help] to learn more about the site, including [ask], as well as [what is on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Please also follow the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).